# Can I double my dataset by including opposites?

Tags: regression, logistic

The data set I'm working with is a set of votes. Experts in a field vote for outcome A or outcome B and I'm running a logistic regression to get a feel for how the intensity of the majority vote relates to the actual probability of the outcome.

For example, if in Case 1, 51% of experts think that a given outcome is more likely and in Case 2, 86% of experts think a given outcome is more likely, I would expect the real probability of the outcome in Case 2 to be higher than Case 1.

Currently I'm only considering the majority side of the case. So in keeping with the above example I'd only be using 51% vote for outcome A and 86% vote for outcome B in my logistic regression inputs. In effect:

[.51, .86]
[A, B]

Could I also include the minority predication as well? To the effect of:

[.51, .49, .86, .14]
[A, B, B, A]

I have this vague thought that it would double my data. At the same time, since I'm really only interested in the portion of the X axis that is above 50%, I'm concerned that I'd be spending time and effort on a portion of the graph that isn't really relevant.

Comment: If I understand your thought correctly, there is no extra information to be added here. In fact you just be confusing the issue as the mean outcome could only ever be 0.5.

Comment: It sounds like you understood yes. I had this hazy idea that using the minority vote value would force the 50% probability point of the regression to always sit on the .50 vote majority point of the x-axis. While that may not be true, your concise phrasing makes a lot of sense to me and re-enforces the idea that it's not a good approach. I wish I could give you the answer for that.

Comment: Thanks is thanks enough!

Comment: A more fruitful exercise, in my opinion, is to gather potential information metrics to account for why  'experts' get it wrong (aka, the surprise win). It not a question of models, but better information used in even less sophisticated models.